# Control interpretation by Import

Tags: import, date-and-time, interpreter

When I `Import` an Excel file, sometimes *Mathematica* interprets the dates as `DateObject`s, and sometimes it doesn't. How can I control whether and when such interpretation is done?

Comment: I guess it depends on format of the cell data in Excel. The same formatting leads to similar interpretation in Mathematica.

Comment: Have you considered using `SemanticImport`? There you can choose the data format for each column with the second argument.

Comment: @Rom That is a good point, but one of the things I might like to do is import as (say) a string regardless of the format of the cell.

Comment: @JEM Yes. If you specify `"String"` format, it interprets as a `DateObject` and then converts to a `String`.

Comment: @CarbonFlambe, You can use the `Interpreter` to be sure that imported object is interpreted namely as you need. Something like `Interpreter["DateTime"][<your data>]`

Comment: @Rom I'm sorry, but I can't see how to do this when I don't yet have access to the data, its not yet having been imported into Mathematica.

Comment: @CarbonFlambe, No-no! `Interpreter` have to be applied to already imported data. So, first, you will run `a=Import["data.xlsx"]` and further `b=Interpreter["DateTime"][a]`.

Comment: @Rom Yes, that's what I'm saying. `Import` generally interprets dates as `DateObject`s. How to `Import` _without_ interpreting the dates as `DateObject`s?

Comment: @CarbonFlambe, The xlsx - is complicated format where you can obtain more or less right data just in case if it is imported according to inner rules. However, you can check the `Head` of imported data and apply your own interpretation. For example, if your first column is Date, then you can use something like `DateString[First@#, "ISODate"] & /@ importeddata`.You will have strings instead of the `DateObject`s

Comment: Thank you @Rom, but the interpretation as a `DateObject` destroys information in the data. I need the raw information. I can get it by saving the Excel file to a CSV and importing the CSV; but I want to get it from the Excel file directly.